# JavaScript code explanation (events + canvas) [sigma.js]

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sigma.js

Here is some code that I have from [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/examples/more_node_info.html):

```
function f(event)
    {
        sigInst.iterNodes(function(n){
        node = n;
        },[event.content[0]]);

        alert();
    }


sigInst.bind('click',f).bind('outnodes',f).draw();
```

I don't understand this:

1. from where function `f` gets the `event`? no one passes it.
2. line `},[event.content[0]]);`

Can I add events to canvas elements? sigma.js draws a canvas and then (I don't understand how) there is an event listeners on `click` and `outnodes`. How does this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from where function f gets the event? no one passes it.

it is sent automatically by the `bind` function  - when the handler is executed.

> line },[event.content[0]]);

It's just an argument for the `iterNodes` function which is an array of size 1 which has the value of a property named  content which is also  an array , so it takes its first cell.

Comment: I don't know if `bind` do this, the documentation is very poor

Comment: @VladIoffe Poor documentation is not an indication of "unsure of". trust me. its just like  jQuery. this is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Sigma uses its own custom events dispatcher. As you can see here:

https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/classes/eventdispatcher.js#L129

It dispatches events with certain parameters of its own. When you `bind` to something, it always is executed through some sort of dispatch/trigger. The dispatch/trigger, as seen in the link, adds custom parameters which is why you're able to access `content`.

Comment: do you know is thee is any sigma.js file which is not minifide?

Comment: If you clone the repo and run this command: cat ./src/intro.js `find ./src/classes -name "*.js"` ./src/sigmaintro.js `find ./src/core -name "*.js"` `find ./src/public -name "*.js"` ./src/sigmaoutro.js > build/sigma.concat.js` 

It will create a concatenated version of the library.

Comment: Here, I did it for you with the latest version. https://gist.github.com/mattkenefick/6512949